# Placing a link with onClick property in django helptext field

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a model form

class RegularUserFormStep1(ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = RegularUser
    fields = ('school', 'grad_date',)
    help_texts = {'school':mark_safe("<a id='school_add' href = '#' onClick='ModalToggle('{% url 'schools_add' %}','{% url 'schools_add' %}','#form','Add school'); return false;' >Add</a>")}
```

But when I try to click the link, 
I get the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

So, I want to ask what is the right way to embed links containing django template variables in field helptext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is not treated as a Django template, so you can not use the `url` template tag.

Instead of

```
{% url 'schools_add' %}
```

You can use the [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)  to get the url

```
schools_add_url = reverse('schools_add')
```

then substitute it into your string.

```
help_texts = {
    'school': mark_safe(
        "<a id='school_add' href = '#' onClick='ModalToggle('%s','%s','#form','Add school'); return false;' >Add</a>" % (schools_add_url, schools_add_url)
    )
}
```

You should always be careful when using `mark_safe` for help text. In this case, you are not including any content from the user, so it's ok.

Comment: Thank you! I have completly forgotten that I can use reverse to build urls. But I think it's better to use reverse_lazy